# My Minecraft skin will not change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to change my minecraft skin. I get it to my Mojang account all right, but when I click “Change”, it says “Bad Request” and it never loads. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of recently, you can change your skin through the minecraft launcher. Basically you start the launcher, press `skins`. Then you can choose your image and upload it. It may take some time before the changes are actually applied.

I have assumed that you use the Java Edition and the latest launcher.

About the 'Bad Request': Perhaps Mojang has removed the functionality to change skins via the website, but I can't say that for sure.